# Thinnest rigid packings of the plane

Tags: discrete-geometry

A packing of the plane with copies of any shape is called rigid (or "stable") if every unit is fixed by its neighbors, i.e., no unit can be translated without disturbing others in the packing. We are interested in thin rigid packings of the plane, rigid packings that that leave the largest possible fraction of the plane uncovered.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidCirclePacking.html shows a way to achieve the thinnest rigid packing of the plane with unit circles - with density zero.

1. What is the thinnest rigid packing of the plane with unit squares? Is it a non-lattice arrangement? I do not know any references.
2. Which is the convex shape for which the densest and thinnest rigid packings of the plane differ the **least** in terms of coverage of the plane?

Note: For example, with thin rectangles or thin triangles, we observe (https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2020/03/thinnest-rigid-packings-contd.html) that difference in coverage can be arbitrarily high: indeed, the densest packing of the plane is a perfect tiling and the thinnest rigid pack can leave an arbitrarily large fraction of the plane uncovered.

Comment: See [this question and answers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/145314/767) for packings with zero density.

Comment: Why do you write "probably" the thinnest? The packing by Böröczky cited on that page  and in the linked question has density zero. Are you suggesting there may be ones with negative density?

Comment: thanks... made a corrective edit.

Comment: The question now is: is there a shape which does *not* admit density zero rigid packings?

Comment: For unit squares I believe you should be able to use the structure in the mathworld illustration, replacing the circles with alternating coordinate-aligned squares and 45-degree-rotated squares so that each square of one orientation is wedged between three squares of the other orientation.

Comment: Thanks TonyK. the link you gave shows the construction given in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidCirclePacking.html is not quite optimal (zero density) -  The construction drawn by Prof. O'Rourke does not look a straight enhancement of the picture given in the above Mathworld page. And yes, after some experimentation, I am unable to see how the kind of construction beginning with a hexagonal lattice of disks can be naturally done with unit squares.

Comment: And Wojowu, I too would like an answer to the question you raised. Thanks

Comment: The construction given on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145314/are-there-locally-jammed-arrangements-of-spheres-of-zero-density probably works for zero density arrangements with half-disks (semidisks) too - this appears to follow from all boundaries between a region with disks and the empty region being concave polylines as noted there.